# use git branch for developing and testing online

Tags: git

I need a way to test changes online before publishing them.
So far git can play a role in this from what i read. I have little knowledge when it comes to git so ...

the preliminary info is:
1) website domain is: http://www.domain.com
2) the is a dns redirection using the "*" wildcard
      *.domain.com => www.domain.com

1) I think i should use a development branch ... but how can i test that branch live?
2) What link would i use to access that branch and how do i set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've already read some git tutorials, I like to recommend [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com).

You can use simple setup for the beginning - **keep two branches - one (master) with stable, tested code and one with the code you develop**. [Here is a good article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) describing a good, but full scale git branching model, so you can see how it looks in bigger projects.

It is good to **have some automated way of deploying code into the server**. When you have one (using some CI tool or scripts which check out the repository, copy necessary files, run the database migrations etc.) it is easy to deploy your application to any location (for example a designated test server). I would not risk testing new code on a production server, but if you are short on money you can do that. **Remember to set up the separate copy of the database** for development application!

When you stabilize the code and it can be used in the production you **merge development branch with master branch**.

Comment: thanks for the article and comments ... how do i automate the way of deploying code into the server? cron jobs or what? i have no pb to manually merge the development branch to the master once i am done .... what i want is when i need to program something .... create the development branch ... so imeddaitly after that command the dev.domain.com link should point to the new branch ... so how do i set this up?

Comment: Cron is not a good idea. You shoud write a script for your specific configuration and run it when you want to have new version on your server (which happens after pushing some commits to a repository). You can use ssh to run `git clone` on your server.

Comment: Actions ran after a committing or pushing to the repository can be automated using "git hooks" (go to Google for details).

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to deploy your development branch in a different location on your server and use subdomains.
For example, www.domain.com would be your production and dev.domain.com would be your test branch.
The subdomains would point to a different location on the server.
You can set this up in your web server configuration. 
For more security, I also recommend to limit the access on your development subdomain using a password or an IP white list.

If you tell me more about your configuration on your server, I may be able to show you the configuration.
For a starter, what web server do you use?

Comment: hi koleror, i have a managed rackspace server with CentOS ... did i answer ur question?

Comment: Not really. Ok so basically, do you have a full control of your server configuration? Do you have root access on it? If not, you should probably ask to your provider to help you...

Comment: i have ssh but i can also ask them to do things for me ... i do not know what to tell them to do :))) like ... step 1) create a subdomain called dev step 2) .... uhhh i do not know :))

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workflow.

I have 3 main branches :

1. Master, this branch reflects the main website : website.com
2. Develop, this branch reflects the dev website : dev.website.com
3. Preprod, to add another level of testing, you may not need it.

Each feature is coded on a branch that is based on develop. Develop is then merged on master when proved to be stable.

My web server syncs the develop branch with the dev subdomain, and the master branch with the main domain.

Comment: my biggest confusion is how to i set up the server to point to a branch? i mean ... when i create a subdomain i have to specify a location on the server ... i do not know if git's branch can be linked to that location somehow :|

Comment: As I said, simply deploy your branches in 2 different locations on your server and point your subdomains on the correct locations

Comment: When we talk about deploy we mean your own script which invokes `git clone` and checks out chosen branch. Probably you'd like to do more things when deploying your application (migrating a database, restarting application server etc.)

Comment: I have a folder /var/www/website.com and another one /var/www/dev.website.com, each of them is used by the web server as a virtual host.

Comment: so far i only deployed php code ... so this would suffice for now :) ... ok i think i need to start doing some tests and crash some things to start learning :)

Comment: If you only have PHP code, it's quite easy to set up then. Step 1) deploy your development branch on a different location on your server. Step 2) Set up your web server (e.g. apache or nginx) to make a virtual domain pointing on your new development folder.

Comment: but i need to duplicate my project right? the duplicate folder would be for the dev subdomain and when i am done with that i have to use git somehow to push the changes into the master branch right?